# When running flutter app on window it show following error

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path = 'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\testapp\testapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\path_provider_windows' (OS Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
, errno = 183)
Exited (sigterm)
```

when I launch flutter app on windows it show following error
tried flutter clean but nothing works secondly checked flutter doctor everything is fine all  green tick

Comment: It will be easier to look into the issue if you can share the full code or whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue
**Step #1**
In your project windows folder find flutter/ephemeral folder and delete that folder **Most probably you have to delete following folder** also from linux folder if that doesn't work first.
**step #2**
Run flutter clean command then run app will hopefully work fine

***Disclaimer***

Following method work in my case in your case can't guarantee that will work same way.

Thanks